# Change link text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link within a Bootstrap 3 accordion like this:

```
<a id="bedlink1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#myaccordion" aria-expanded="true" href="#bed1"> <i class="material-icons pull-left">arrow_drop_down</i>Bed 1</a>
```

I need to change the text "Bed 1" in the link to a different value.  To do this, I used the following jQuery code:

```
$("#bedlink1").text("Bed 2");
```

That results in the link text being changed to "Bed 2" as expected but the icon defined with the  tag disappears.

I also tried:

```
$("#bedlink1").text('<i class="material-icons pull-left">arrow_drop_down</i> Bed 2');
```

That resulted in the  tag being displayed as text as well as "Bed 2".

How can I set the text of this link and retain the icon defined by the  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#bedlink1").get(0).lastChild.nodeValue = "Bed 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bedlink1').html('My New Link Text or HTML');
```